# In Dreamweaver update record only if user write something in a texta area

Tags: php, dreamweaver

In Dreamweaver (php) I have a form with a question like: "How did you hear about us?" and a radio group with some choices. One of the radio group choices is "Other - please describe!". When selected, a text area changes from hidden to show and the user can write something. I am not able to update a record with user's selection in one table field (I can save either radio group selection or text area). Any help? Thank you!

Comment: have you tried anything of your own?

Comment: Of course! My problem is to "combine" radio group with text area.

Comment: show some code you have tried

Comment: I tried to do something like this after radio group (proposal) and text area (proposal_text). <?php
       if(isset($_POST['proposal_text']))
      {$answer = $_POST['proposal_text'];}
    else {$answer = $_POST['proposal'];} 
            ?>

Comment: @Tornado - Thank you for your answer. Now, everything is clear! For your kindness I would like to give something back. I know! I will give you an advice. In the future, if you see somebody drowning please, please, please... do not ask him if he has a pool! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. *Proposal* is the radio group and *ProposalText* is the textarea.

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
if ($_POST['Proposal'] != 'Other - please describe!') {
    $_POST['ProposalText'] = $_POST['Proposal'];
    }
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE dialog SET answer=%s WHERE id_question=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['ProposalText'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id_question'], "int"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['proposal_text']) {
      $answer = $_POST['proposal_text'];
} else {
      $answer = $_POST['proposal'];
}
```

What for isset()? It will check if such field exist and if your 'proposal_text' is just hidden it will be still send so it will exist and you will be always save value of $_POST['proposal_text'].

```
if($_POST['proposal_text'])  - will check if $_POST['proposal_text'] have any value
```

Comment: I will try in on Monday. About isset? I was thinking to check if the variable is not null but you are right, is only hidden.

Comment: It is not working. Maybe if I will send the radio selection to the textarea?